# Matplotlib subplots using imshow don't share same pixel size. Images don't maintain consistent scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to export weather patterns to use as UVs. So they all need to be on one image. But when I try to plot the weather data in one image all the images have different scaling. The pixels aren't squares and some images are smaller than others.

I've tried forcing extents, aspect ratios, changing the subplot layout, figure size. But it's all messed up.

[image: Weather Export]

The first set of images are 160x100, second set are 100x45 and the final set are 160x45. Meaning the middle images should be half the height of the left most images and the right most images should be the same height as the middle images.

I'd just load them into PIL but the data includes 'NaN' values for the oceans which PIL can't handle. I'd be happy with either a way to maintain pixel scale across subplots or a way to use NaN values in PIL without converting them into zeros.

code is below. It's just a loop that slices through an array.

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(90,10))
    plt.subplot(161).imshow(front)
    plt.subplot(161).axis('off')
    plt.subplot(162).imshow(back)
    plt.subplot(162).axis('off')
    plt.subplot(163).imshow(left)
    plt.subplot(163).axis('off')
    plt.subplot(164).imshow(right)
    plt.subplot(164).axis('off')
    plt.subplot(165).imshow(top)
    plt.subplot(165).axis('off')
    plt.subplot(166).imshow(bottom)
    plt.subplot(166).axis('off')
    plt.savefig(directory+str(num)+'.png')
    #plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise the axis limits such that each axis covers a range of 160×100 pixels. Because all axes have the same size, this automatically implies each pixel in the axes is also the same size. This requires some calculation (especially to get the images centred in the axes), which I will try to explain below.

First, let us simply set the `xlim` and `ylim` values of all axes to those of the first axis (the one with the largest dataset). Note that I am writing the plotting code slightly differently, but you should be able to see the similarities quite easily. I am also generating some random data for visualisation as I do not have the dataset you are using.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

front  = np.random.uniform(size=(100, 160))
back   = np.random.uniform(size=(100, 160))
left   = np.random.uniform(size=(45, 100))
right  = np.random.uniform(size=(45, 100))
top    = np.random.uniform(size=(45, 160))
bottom = np.random.uniform(size=(45, 160))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 6, figsize=(9, 1))
for i, data in enumerate([front, back, left, right, top, bottom]):
    ax[i].imshow(data)
    ax[i].set_axis_off()  # corresponds to plt.subplot(x).axis('off')
    ax[i].set_xlim(ax[0].get_xlim())
    ax[i].set_ylim(ax[0].get_ylim())
```

This produces the following figure:

[image: figure with correctly scaled pixels, but all images are aligned to the top left]

Simply doing this gives us axes with correctly scaled pixels, however, the images are all aligned to the top left of the axes. I presume you want the images to be centred. For this, we need an additional coordinate transformation of the limits we set, where we move the smaller image by half of the difference between the width of the smaller image and the width of the larger image horizontally. Transforming the vertical coordinate is analogous, but using the height difference of the images. We can write some code to automatically do this for us:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 6, figsize=(9, 1))
for i, data in enumerate([front, back, left, right, top, bottom]):
    ax[i].imshow(data)
    ax[i].set_axis_off()  # corresponds to plt.subplot(x).axis('off')
    half_x_diff = (front.shape[1] - data.shape[1]) / 2
    half_y_diff = (front.shape[0] - data.shape[0]) / 2
    ax[i].set_xlim((lim - half_x_diff for lim in ax[0].get_xlim()))
    ax[i].set_ylim((lim - half_y_diff for lim in ax[0].get_ylim()))
```

This produces the following figure:

[image: figure with correctly scaled pixels, and images centred within their axes]

The images are now correctly centered within their axes. Note that, because we are centering images with different sizes in axes with constant sizes, the distance between the images is not consistent. However, correctly solving this while ensuring pixel scales are maintained is mathematically more complicated.

Comment: Holy shit. Thank you so much!! I can't believe how much effort you put into helping me.